# Is there any evidence for American atrocities during the Soviet-Afghan War?

Tags: united-states, cold-war, war-crime, afghanistan

I just spoke to someone that was convinced that US soldiers committed rapes against Afghan women during the Cold War.

Is there any truth to this?

Were there any US soldiers deployed to Afghanistan during this period?

They explained they read accounts of these atrocities this year.
Is this fake news? Russian propaganda?

First place I looked was Wikipedia page for [United States war crimes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_war_crimes). Nothing in the list of American war-crimes. In fact that page goes straight from Vietnam to the War on Terror, with nothing in between.

Then I checked more general lists of war crimes, but nothing. I also checked about the Soviet-Afghan war. It appears [there was US intelligence there](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIA_activities_in_Afghanistan), but no "boots on the ground".

This came about due to conversations about Palestinian relations with the US prior to 9-11, so I thought this was maybe Soviet or Arab propaganda. I checked Snopes and found nothing.

The person I was talking to refused to give me the article they read earlier this year. But seemed adamant they weren't conflating this with some other conflict. This wasn't an internet troll, but someone I know personally.

Can anyone point me to a source for this? Either reliable or otherwise?

Comment: You spoke to a crazy or heavily misinformed person. They might have been reading accounts of *Soviet* atrocities - which included rape against Afghan women - but somehow confused the instigators with Americans.

Comment: In future conversations it might be a good idea to ask "someone": Where did you get that from? Where is the evidence, do you have sources? Cursory search yields nothing on that claim for me in these timeframes (for the claim *or* the report). Won't say that proves anything or that it would be impossible, but unless this question can be backed up to prove it's more than just one mixup/rumour picked up in an overgeard conversation with a single pundit:

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be based on a single man (not the OP) spreading implausible rumours. Please provide evidence that at least one other person news outlet holds this claim to be true also.

Comment: That's what I'm asking for

Comment: Perhaps extend your search for Russian sites/blogs. In case you find *someone else* with these allegations, we can look into it further, or perhaps it's a nice fit on Skeptics.SE? Btw, thanks for the edit!

Comment: The hive mind has spoken: take "someone" with a grain of salt.